# SQlite file cannot be loaded/ Android studio 2.0

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to read SQLite database which I created on WIndows PC. 
I only want to read out a table and display on a listview.
Is it not possible to access any database on emulator?
I placed "DIC.db" on the Assets folder. Its table name is DIC.
It has four columns, one integer, three text columns.
I created it with DB Browser for SQLite (PC).
I want to create a dictionary. ID, JApanese, English and Pronounciation. 
Please give me your advice.

---

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DBNAME = "DIC.db";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void openDatabase() {
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if(mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
    return;
    }
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if(mDatabase!=null) {mDatabase.close();}
}
public List<SDic> getListWord() {
    SDic sDic = null;
    List<SoccerDic> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DIC", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    soccerDic = new SDic(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
wordList.add(sDic);
cursor.moveToNext();
    }
cursor.close();
closeDatabase();
return wordList;
}
```

}

Comment: this is a largely documented procedure. google has tons of examples on how to do that.

Comment: Assuming your code is correct, where did you place the database in the emulator?

Comment: There is a library that helps with this. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 0):

Need more details about your problem. I am assuming that you are not being able to open the database. If it is the case then you might want look into the following line and verify the path from debugger or print it our with Log command.

```
String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
```

Path to the asset folder is `<App Name>/assets/`

Answer to you question is yes, it is possible to place sqlite db inside asset folder but what you need to know is asset folder is accessible at run time. So you may consider to open the schema from asset folder and then copy the database to other plsces of your choice e.g `/data/data/<appname>/database`.

```
InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outfilename = Constants.DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

File checkFolder = new File(Constants.DB_PATH);
if(!checkFolder.exists()) {
    checkFolder.mkdirs();
}

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

// transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
    myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
}

//Close the streams
myoutput.flush();
myoutput.close();
myinput.close();
//Open the database
String mypath = Constants.DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
if(myDataBase == null) {
   myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

Comment: Copying the file seems like too much work. The library in the comments above is all that is needed.

Comment: There are two part to the answer, first one is how to open it from the asset folder as it is and then there is option of moving it to somewhere else. The library seems interesting though some projects may not have the flexibility to use third party libraries.